# Refresh child controls in flowlayoutpanel when scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

In .NET 3.5 with winforms I'm making an image thumbnail viewer control.

The main control is derived from a `FlowLayoutPanel` which takes a list of images and displays them. The images which are displayed are made from a `CustomControl` on which I paint the and the accompanying label as well as the border of the control.
Images can be selected through clicking and yada yada as you would expect for that kind of control.

Here's a screenshote to illustrate:

[image]

That part works fine. The problem is then when I scroll the `FlowLayoutPanel` derived control the border doesn't redraw properly and there are lines remaining as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I have set both the `FlowLayoutPanel` and the Images to double buffered. And the images and labels do not have the problem, so I suspect it is something else, but can't figure out what it is.

I think the method used to paint the border of the images might be at fault. Here's the code I use:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle captionContainer;

        captionContainer = new Rectangle();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Caption))
            captionContainer = this.DrawCaption(e.Graphics);

        if (this.Image != null)
            this.DrawImage(e.Graphics, captionContainer);

        this.Size = new Size(this.Padding.Horizontal + this.ImageSize.Width, this.Padding.Vertical + this.ImageSize.Height + captionContainer.Height);

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, this.currentBorderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

I'll post more code if needed, but it is pretty lengthy, so I do not want to put too much code unless it actually is necessary.

Can anybody see where this is going wrong?

Comment: Solved it. Although I'd like to know what exactly was wrong with the method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by also drawing the border using the `Graphics` object. Replacing

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, this.currentBorderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

with

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(this.currentBorderColor, 1F), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1)));
```

does the trick. No idea why one works and not the other though...